# Find if a word in an SQL query is in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, replace

I need a way to search for a word within an SQL query, and to be able to determine whether or not that word is within a subquery or the main query.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT product_id 
                 FROM tagmap 
                 WHERE tag_id = 1)
```

I need to replace the instance of the word `WHERE` with, say, `WHERE 1=1 AND` in the query string, but only in the main query, not in the subquery.

This is only an example of the issue I'm facing. The real queries are much bigger than this and contain several subqueries! Also, there are hundreds of queries I need to do this for, so I need to be able to do this automatically.

Comment: Can this question be expressed as you just need to replace any instance of `WHERE` with `WHERE 1=1 AND`, so long as the `WHERE` does not occur inside `( .. )`?   Do you need to do this within a text/query editor, or programmatically over eg a sql script file (in which case, which language?)

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm looking for. I need to do this using a text-editor preferably.

Comment: Is there `WHERE` that needs replacement always at the left margin, while the subqueries are always indented?

Comment: No, the layout above is just syntax highlighting - it is normally just an inline string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* the following regex:

```
(?<!\(.*)\b(WHERE)\b|\b(WHERE)\b(?!.*\))
```

will match any instance of "WHERE":

- that occurs to the *left* of the first *opening* parenthesis, or
- that occurs to the *right* of the last *closing* parenthesis.

ie Won't detect instances of WHERE that occur *inside* a `(..)`.

It's worked on the few test cases I've tried... and I'm not going to do any more testing without further clarifcation of your requirements...

EG below, I've indicated the matched instances by surrounding with tildes: `~WHERE~`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
~WHERE~ id NOT IN 
    (SELECT product_id FROM tagmap WHERE tag_id = 1 and (SELECT true WHERE something) );

SELECT x FROM y ~WHERE~ z = z;

SELECT Count(*) 
FROM (Select rows FROM table WHERE filter) 
~WHERE~ z
```

I'd *strongly* recommend you test this thoroughly before relying on it.

---

**EDIT: A basic .NET implementation...** because I've got VS open at the moment... ;-)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("pathToSqlScript.sql");
        string oldSQLString = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string newSQLString = Regex.Replace(oldSQLString, @"(?<!\(.*)\b(WHERE)\b|\b(WHERE)\b(?!.*\))", @"WHERE 1=1 AND");
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("newSqlScript.sql");
        sw.Write(newSQLString);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT: To do this in a text editor...**

Visual Studio will allow you do perform a search/replace based on a regex.  I'd imagine something like Notepad++ would do it (at least with the aid of a plugin).  Or this might help you: http://www.regular-expressions.info/editpadpro.html

Otherwise, knock up something that'll read/modify your text file, eg using PHP, .NET, Java, ....

Comment: I've tested this on a sample of my data and it has worked fine. I will do a dummy run before committing it fully. Thank you very much.